# Check if age groups in multidimensional array conflict

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
array (age) {
    [0] -> 
        [0] =>12
        [1] => -
        [2] =>16
    [1] -> 
        [0] =>14
        [1] => -
        [2] =>18
}
```

I have a dynamic multidimensional array that holds age groups. I want to check these if these age groups overlap one another. In the example above: age group 12-16 would overlap with 14-18 and in this case I want to throw an error.

If tried having nested foreach and for loops but i just can seem to get it right.

heres what I’ve tried:

```
foreach ($group as $k => $g) {
  $g1[] = $g[0];
  $g2[] = $g[2];
}

foreach ($g1 as $k => $g) {
  if ($g < $g2[$k]) {
    foreach ($g2 as $l => $gg) {
      if ($gg < $g[$l]) {
        echo 'overlap';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see I’ve gone with separating the array into two but this doesn’t seem to be effective. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the array always have three values and are keys 0 and 2 always the upper and lower bounds?

Comment: @chris85 yeah it will always look like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create for both age groups an array range and look if there are any similarities (array_intersect()).

```
$age_range1 = range($array[0][0], $array[0][2]);
$age_range2 = range($array[1][0], $array[1][2]);
$intersect = array_intersect($age_range1, $age_range2);
if(count($intersect) > 0) {
    //throw exception
}
```

If the age group array is dynamic (more than 2), you need of course to generate the array ranges dynamically and compare it with each other through two loops.

```
$array = array(0 => array(0 => 12, 2 => 18), 1 => array(0 => 19, 2 => 20), 2 => array(0 => 19, 2 => 35));

$similarities = false;
for($k = 0; $k < count($array); $k++) {
    $master = range($array[$k][0], $array[$k][2]);

    for($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        $age_range = range($array[$i][0], $array[$i][2]);
        $intersect = array_intersect($master, $age_range);
        if(count($intersect) > 0) {
            $similarities = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if($similarities == true) {
    echo 'found exception'; //throw exception
} else {
    echo 'found nothing';
}
```